# Trouble getting the end of the ponytail red and black on the other side of the bead (Solved)

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

Ok so, I’m trying to make my OC Zoro into 3D but I cant make the end be red and the red become black. Can someone help?

Comment: are you using an image as mask (as factor in a Mix Shader or in a Mix RGB)?

Comment: I’m completely new at this. So basically I’m gonna be confused a lot.

Comment: maybe pack your images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, you need to pack your images before saving and sharing (File > External Data > Pack Resources). If it's too heavy for blend-exchange, use another platform like workupload or other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see if you open the *Image Editor* and open the image that is used to color these parts, the colors are inverted, it is red where it is supposed to be black and vice-versa:

[image]

A quick fix would be to choose the side or top view, switch to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>U</kbd> and unwrap with the *Project from View* option:

[image]

In the *UV Editor* put the island over the image so that the red comes at the tip of the tail:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: However, the hair at the front needs to stay black, and the spikes needs to be red.

Comment: @ZoroTheZoroark I've edited my answer, re-unwrap is probably the easiest way

Comment: Found it. Had to go to vertical mode then head back to edit mode in layout.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Ok update, I cant seem to color everything in black cause the bead is LITERALLY in the way.

Comment: But I tried to copy your vertical that’s located and I can’t seem to align it correctly.

Comment: You need to select only the tip in the 3D view, to do that put your mouse cursor on it and press L, then press U (unwrap) > Project from View

Comment: Then, how I get the bead out the way? I’m trying to paint the remain red colors to black.

Comment: Ok, I did a different approach but, my friend must've forgotten to pack the resources.